# Pass ArrayList in cursor using a ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor, adapter

so, Im trying to build an app to show a dinner menu.
So I have a ListView that contains the weekdays, and every listView item contains another ListView with all the available menus.

Now i'm trying to bind the data to th UI using CursorAdapter, that gets it's data from a contentprovider, that get's it's data from a database. The data is stored by meal (1 table, columns: week, weekday, meal, price)

So currently I get a cursor with all meals from 1 week (for example 2 entries for monday, 3 for tuesday, ...)

Then in the bindView method of the outer ListView adapter I create a viewholder with the important data for the UI, it currently looks something like this

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

 viewHolder.dateView.setText(cursor.getString(MainActivityFragment.COL_WEEKDAY));

    ListView mealListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_dailymenu);
    mealListView.setAdapter(mMenuSingleDayAdapter);
    mMenuSingleDayAdapter.swapCursor(...);
```

now I kind of need the cursor, that gets passed to the bindView method (using loaders) to not pass every single meal, but pass an arraylist for every day of the week instead, that contains all available meals.

Do I even use the proper adapter for that?

hope my question makes any sense to you :/

Comment: *hope my question makes any sense to you* ... sorry, no, it doesn't ... Cursor has no capabilities to store an array ... also ListView is not a good containter for this ... for me it looks like a job for ExpandableListView ...

Comment: So what Adapter would you suggest to use? And I considered ExpandableListView myself, but I didn't want the Items to be collapsed, the meals should be visible at all time.

Comment: yyyyyyyyy let me think .... yyyyyyy ... ExpandableListAdapter? .... you could also try add the "group"(fx day of the week) headers instead ExpandableListView and then make a use of `SectionIndexer` ... edit: (now i think that it is even better idea ...) google for: sectionindexer usage with cursor (or something simila)

Comment: @Selvin `"Cursor has no capabilities to store an array"` actually it has: a `Bundle`, but it has very limited usage, definitely not in that case

Comment: @pskink could you elaborate how I use a bundle? A Bundle would need to contain 2-3 Meals, a meal contains some basics ints and strings, nothing big.

Comment: i said: `but it has very limited usage, definitely not in that case`